# Java Android : Architecture for background Sync and database management

Tags: android, architecture, background-process

I need to write code for an application that is like CRM (not exactly though) I need to get data from server in background and populate my tables.

And update UI layer when I have new data/when sync finishes, I need to have a background service that checks every minute (when app is running) for any update on server

There are around 25 tables that need constant sync

To start with I want to write some architecture that is memory battery and of course bandwidth effective

are there any opensource framework that I can have look,( I looked into [groundy](https://github.com/telly/groundy) already) to ensure best architecture for my app

Answer (score 0):

you can try **Sync Adapter** 
take a look at this [Creating a Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)